# JRE 8 for Install4j on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I use Install4j 5.1.8 on a Windows 7 machine and I was not able to find any JRE 8 bundle.

[image]

Do I have to create the bundle manually or should I upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bundle format has changed in the 5.1.x series. With install4j 5.1.8 you only see the old bundles that are not updated anymore.

When you update to install4j 5.1.15, the new bundles will be listed. Those include 8.x bundles.